# argparse accept everything

Tags: python, argparse

Is there a way to have an `argparse.ArgumentParser` not raise an exception upon reading an unknown option, but rather put all the unknown options with values in a dictionary, and those without a value in a list?

For example, say no arguments were defined in the parser for `prog.py`, and I pass two arguments:

```
./prog.py --foo bar --baz
```

I would like the following:

```
parsed = parser.parse_args()
vals = parsed.unknown_with_vals
novals = parsed.unknown_without_vals

print(vals)
#{'foo' : 'bar'}
print(novals)
#['baz']
```

Can this be done?

Comment: what would you want it to do if invoked like this? `./prog.py --foo bar baz --quux`? Should the dictionary be `{"foo": ["bar", "baz"]}`? Should *this* be an error? Should `baz` be consider a positional argument? You're basically asking for a whole new argument parser: I think in general you're better off just using something like the argparse.REMAINDER` value for `nargs` to accumulate everything unexpected into a list, and then do your own processing on it: http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#nargs

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
known, unknown_args = parser.parse_known_args(...)
```

As @ben w noted in the comment how do you parse `unknown_args` is upto you e.g., with the following grammar:

```
unknown_args = *(with_val / without_val) EOS
with_val = OPT 1*VALUE
without_val = OPT
OPT = <argument that starts with "--">
VALUE = <argument that doesn't start with "--">
```

Or as a regex:

```
(O V+ | O)* $
```

Note: orphan values are forbidden in this case.

#### [Example](http://ideone.com/RKwed)

```
d = {}
for arg in unknown_args:
    if arg.startswith('--'): # O
        opt = arg
        d[opt] = []
    else: # V
        d[opt].append(arg) #NOTE: produces NameError if an orphan encountered

with_vals = {k: v for k, v in d.items() if v}
without_vals = [k for k, v in d.items() if not v]
```