# Python argparse parse unrecognised arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

I have a parser with 3-4 arguments, which works well. I want to supply an unknown number of extra arguments to the script, which would get loaded into a template. I've read the argparse documentation, but I'm not sure it's possible. I can `parse_known_arguments()`, but I still have to handle the `["--placeholder1", "value1", "--placeholder2", "value2", ...]` array myself. Should I go ahead with that, or is there a more pythonic way?

Just from the top of my head:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--template", required=True)
parser.add_argument("--location", required=True)
args,unknown = parser.parse_known_arguments()
tpl = LoadTemplate(args.template)

# Missing part where I transform unknown into an dict or namespace called extraarguments
raw = tpl.render(extraarguments)

# Print into args.location raw
render.py --template template1 --location /path/to/invoices --author John --customer Customer1 --title "Your invoice is ready!"
render.py --template template2 --location /path/to/newsletter --customer Customer2 --sender john@store.com --subject "Weekly newsletter"
```

In both cases, the `template` and `location` have to be present, but the extra arguments should be unpacked and sent into the template rendering function. It looks like a one-liner, but is there a more pythonic way of doing it?

Comment: Just plain extra arguments, or a bunch of unknown options with (possibly) arguments? Give some examples of command line input you're expecting, to clarify your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [argparse accept everything](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643248/argparse-accept-everything)

Comment: If you illustrate how you would handle that list of extras, we might be able to suggest a better way.

Comment: Can you give us some examples of command arguments that would like `argparse` parse?

Comment: Just use `docopt`, it will make you smile.

Comment: There will be absolutely no way for my program to know the names of the extra arguments.  I don't see how `docopt` can help me.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming the `unknown` list is an alternating list of keys and values, it can be turned into a dictionary with:

```
adict = dict(zip(unknown[:-1:2],unknown[1::2]))
```

The zip part turns the list in a list of pairs, which then is turned into a dictionary.  You may want process the values a bit more to remove the '--' prefix from the keys.  You may need a more explicit iteration if you need to check for errors, such as mismatch 'key value' sequences.

Here's a version that leaves the '--' intact:

```
templates = {'template1': "from: {--author} to: {--customer} re: {--title}",
             'template2': "from: {--sender} to: {--customer} re: {--subject}"}

def parser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--template", required=True, choices=templates)
    parser.add_argument("--location", required=True)
    args,unknown = parser.parse_known_args()
    extraarguments = dict(zip(unknown[::2], unknown[1::2]))
    tpl = templates[args.template]
    raw = tpl.format(**extraarguments)
    return raw
print parser()
```

With your 2 samples this produces:

```
In [25]: run stack30139426.py --template template1 --location /path/to/invoices --author John --customer Customer1 --title "Your invoice is ready!"
from: John to: Customer1 re: Your invoice is ready!

In [26]: run stack30139426.py --template template2 --location /path/to/newsletter --customer Customer2 --sender john@store.com --subject "Weekly newsletter"
from: john@store.com to: Customer2 re: Weekly newsletter
```

There have been other SO questions about inputing a dictionary or other unknown key/value pairs.

One suggestion has been to use a `key:value` syntax, and then a simple `[kv.split(':') for kv in unknowns]` to produce a list of pairs:

```
run stack30139426.py --template template2 --location /path/to/newsletter customer:Customer2 sender:john@store.com subject:"Weekly newsletter"
```

Another is to use a JSON syntax

```
run stack30139426.py --template template2 --location /path/to/newsletter '{"customer":"Customer2", "sender":"john@store.com", "subject":"Weekly newsletter"}'
```

Comment: appending a JSON string to the call seems like a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

A way to partially automate the process can be to reuse `argparse` by creating another parser using strings from `unknown` that start with '--' as argument names:

```py
argument_names = [arg for arg in unknown if arg[:2] == '--']
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
for arg in argument_names:
    parser.add_argument(arg)
args = parser.parse_args(unknown)
```

This however will fail if anything but name-value pairs is provided.